# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException при заполнении массива.

Tags: java

Нужно заполнить двумерный 10х10 числами от 1 до 34.чтобы получилось так, как на картинке снизу.
Мой цикл выглядит вот так:

```
    C = 1;
    for (i=9; i>=0; i--)
      for (j=9-i; j<=12-i; j++) 
           if (j>=0) {
              A[i][j] = C; 
               C=C+1;
                }
```

[image: Сама задача]

Компилятор выдает ошибку, хотя по идее должно было быть правильно, но скорее всего у меня где-то ошибка, которую я не могу заметить. Прошу помогите.

Ошибка на строке `A[i][j] = C`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: А что за ошибка то?

Comment: Компилятор выдает следующее
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Ld5171rdb095.main(Ld5171rdb095.java:24) 
на 24 строке находится этот код  A[i][j] = C;

Comment: `j<=12-i` вот это условие явно может быть больше 10, тут и вылетает. Так как задача явно учебная, я настоятельно рекомендую Вам познакомиться с дебагером, чтобы такие вопросы решать самостоятельно за пару минут

Comment: Не уверен, так как с каждым шагом, j увеличивается, а i уменьшается

Comment: В какой то момент у вас `i=0` и тогда `j=12` будет

Comment: Но это условия, для того,чтобы заполнить по 4 числа в строчку, правда в конце из за того, что идет overflow массива может быть выкидывает ошибку?

Comment: Я решил проблему, поменяв значение      if (j>=0)  на    if(j<=9)

Comment: Однако порядок циферок у вас все еще не как в ТЗ :)

Comment: И еще, почитайте соглашения об именовании переменных в Java и старайтесь им следовать.

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы мне помогли :D Я просто начинающий, иногда тупые ошибки попадаются

Comment: У меня до сих пор бывают глупые ошибки. Это не страшно. И познакомьтесь с дебаггером, он сэкономит вам много времени)

Comment: Откат по причине кардинального изменения сути задания после редактирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
C = 1;
for (i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (j = Math.min(9, 12 - i); j >= 9 - i; j++) {
    A[i][j] = C;
    C++;
  }
}
```